# Test if running in utop

Tags: ocaml, prompt, utop

I have added a few lines to my `.ocamlinit` to make the utop prompt less of an eyesore:

```
#require "react";;
#require "lambda-term";;
UTop.prompt := fst (React.S.create LTerm_text.(eval [
    S "\n";
    B_bold true;
    B_fg (LTerm_style.cyan);
    S "# ";
]));;
```

(I don't understand everything that is going on there... I just found it posted online and tweaked it.)

But now if I use the regular `ocaml` toplevel I get:

```
Error: Unbound module UTop
```

Can I add a test to `.ocamlinit` to skip those lines unless I'm running utop? Can I put them in an additional file that is only loaded by utop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you add `#require "utop";;` ?

Comment: I see this error: `Exception:
Invalid_argument
 "The ocamltoplevel.cma library from compiler-libs cannot be loaded inside the OCaml toplevel".` and then `File ".ocamlinit", line 1:
Error: Reference to undefined global Thread` (I skipped a bunch of lines like `/usr/local/lib/ocaml/unix.cma: loaded`). That was my first guess as well :)

Comment: hmmm, it works on my side (updated .ocamlinit like you). I am using ocaml 4.04.0.

Comment: I'm on OCaml 4.04.1. I brushed my config a bit, but I still see `/usr/local/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs/ocamltoplevel.cma: loaded
Exception:
Invalid_argument
 "The ocamltoplevel.cma library from compiler-libs cannot be loaded inside the OCaml toplevel".` when starting the standard toplevel, but utop starts fine.

Comment: On my system it does work. But I was hoping to avoid loading 14 additional modules* when I don't need them, such as when running scripts. * camomile, ocamlcommon, ocamlbytecomp, ocamltoplevel, findlib, findlib_top, lwt, lwt-log, lwt-unix, react, lwt_react, zed, lambda_term, uTop

Comment: @Tobia (1) A workaround (not a very nice though) is to divide your `.ocamlinit` into two files: one for utop and another for the standard toplevel and e.g. make an alias for `ocaml` passing `-init <path-to-ocamlinit-with-no-utop>` to the original toplevel.

Comment: @Tobia (2) In principle we could test `Sys.executable_name` in OCaml code, but there is the problem with `#require` and other directives (this is not valid OCaml code).

Comment: @AntonTrunov I see. I will keep the #require and I will make a different init file if I ever need to. Thanks

Comment: Ideally, utop would use a different init file thank ocaml--let's call it .utoprc--or look for .utoprc before loading .ocamlinit.  People who wanted the same configuration in both could use come kind of include command to run another file from inside .utoprc.